# ML.NET: Why do I have to train a pretrained model?

Tags: .net, tensorflow, machine-learning, ml.net

I want to use a pretrained model (like inceptionV1/V3) for image classification.

So I'm setting up a pipeline in ML.NET where I load this TensorFlow model. But in every tutorial I found there is standing that you have to train that model afterwards to get a model.

E.g. here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification

=> Train the model with the data loaded above:
=> ITransformer model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

Why isn't it possible to just call Fit() without a training data. Because I just want to use the original loaded model without modifications. It is already trained by Google with millions of pictures and should be good enough for all my needs.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not have to train the model again. Just load it then use it to make predictions. The catch is the model was trained on the imagenet data set. This data set has 1000 classes. Your type of images  may or may not be included in the 1000 classes. To make the model customized for your application you should train it using your custom data set. For example if you have a training set of 250 classes of birds with a separate directory for each class and you want to classify birds then you should use the Inception model as follows. I

```
img_size= (224,224)  # set this to the size of images you want to use
img_shape=(224,224,3) # set this to the input image shape
no_of_classes =250     # set this to an integer value for the number of classes
train_dir=r'c:\birds\train'   #point this to your training directory'
t_gen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input,  validation_split=0.3)
train_gen=t_gen.flow_from_directory( directory= train_dir, target_size=img_size, 
           class_mode="categorical",  batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=123, 
           subset='training)
valid_gen=t_gen.flow_from_directory(directory= train_dir, target_size=img_size, 
           class_mode="categorical", batch_size=32, shuffle=False, seed=123, 
           subset='validation')
    
base_model=tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3( include_top=False, weights="imagenet",    
           input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max')
x=basemodel.output
x= Dense(512, activation-'relu')(x)
x= Dropout(.3)(x)
output=Dense(no_of_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history==model.fit(x=train_gen,  epochs=20, verbose=2,   
                  validation_data=valid_gen, shuffle=False,  initial_epoch=0)
```

Comment: I understand that I can train the model for my specific needs. But I just want to use it as it is. The problem is more that ML.NET doesn't allow me to get the model without train, or?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers but it didn't solve my initial problem that I can't get the model without training.

So for other people having the same question I have found a workaround:
I'm not using ML.NET to load the inception model but I'm using now the TensorFlow.NET nuget package to do so. There I can just load a pretrained model and just use it.

Here is the link to an examples project I used:
https://github.com/SciSharp/SciSharp-Stack-Examples/tree/master/src/TensorFlowNET.Examples/ImageProcessing
There are 2 good examples for what I need:

- The File ImageRecognitionInception.cs contains a InceptionV1 model which is used for image classification (watch out: in the comment on top there is standing InceptionV3 but that is wrong. This file definitely uses InceptionV1 model - you can easily see this by the image resolution of 224 pixels. InceptionV3 uses images with 299 pixels).
- The File InceptionArchGoogLeNet.cs contains an InceptionV3 model which is used for image classification.

I hope that helps for people also looking for an easy way to load a pretrained model without the need to retrain it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you never retrain the complete model from zero but just the last few layers.The top layers learn very general features and as we go deep in the network, the layers tend to learn patterns more specific to the task we are dealing with. We are in fact fine-tuning the model to our specific need.

Comment: At least in .NET when I train like in the example I linked then it only predicts one of the training class but not the original 1000 classes. That's why it is so strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `Fit` method an empty data set, e.g.

```
    let tf = mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel modelLocation
    let pipeline = tf.ScoreTensorFlowModel("OutputNode", "InputNode", addBatchDimensionInput = false)
    let data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(Seq.empty<InputType>)
    let model = pipeline.Fit(data)
```

This will load the model and get you the transformer without modifying the tensorflow model.